# javascript event.preventDefault() stops working on production in Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have a javascript method which introduces a couple of keyboard shortcuts, including one which overrides an existing browser command. `Ctrl-G` in both Chrome and Firefox is normally the command to go to the next item in incremental search (usually started by `Ctrl-F`). For my app, I want `Ctrl-G` to prompt for a document id, and take the user to the corresponding document.

On my localhost, it works fine in both Chrome and Firefox. The normal `Ctrl-G` behavior is prevented, and the prompt appears as normal.

When I put the exact same code on the production server, Chrome still works correctly, but Firefox does both my script's action and the default `Ctrl-G` action. Worse, the focus/cursor ends up in the incremental search rather than the prompt dialog, so the user cannot simply ignore it and type in a value.

All the other similar problems I've found have boiled down to `event` not being defined in the handler, and I've got that correct. Other suggestions have been to do `event.preventDefault()` right away, but I only want to `preventDefault()` in some cases and not others.

```
$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    // ignore keyboard shortcuts when in an input
    if (isFocusOnInput()) { return; }

    // get which key was pressed (upper case if Shift, lower if not)
    var key;
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    } else {
        key = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    }

    // the shortcuts themselves.
    if (key == 'h' && typeof hilightMyTasks == 'function') {
        hilightMyTasks();
    } else if (key == 'g' && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        id = prompt('Enter task id','');
        if (id) {
            if (Number(id) == id && id % 1 == 0 && id > 0) {
                window.location.href='/index.php?m=tasks&a=view&task_id='+id+'&tab=0'
            } else {
                alert('Invalid task id!');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And in case it's relevant, the `isFocusOnInput()` method:

```
function isFocusOnInput() {
    var focusType = document.activeElement.type;
    if (focusType == 'text' || focusType == 'textarea' || focusType == 'select-one' ||
            focusType == 'checkbox' || focusType == 'radio' || focusType == 'select-multiple' ||
            focusType == 'password' || focusType == 'hidden' || focusType == 'submit' ||
            focusType == 'reset' || focusType == 'image' || focusType == 'number' ||
            focusType == 'color' || focusType == 'date' || focusType == 'datetime' ||
            focusType == 'datetime-local' || focusType == 'email' || focusType == 'month' ||
            focusType == 'range' || focusType == 'search' || focusType == 'tel' ||
            focusType == 'time' || focusType == 'url' || focusType == 'week' ||
            focusType == 'button') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I just tried doing `e.preventDefault()` before anything else in the method and it still does the default `Ctrl-G` action on Firefox, so it doesn't seem to be a speed/parallel-execution problem.

Comment: If you replace the handler by `function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }` does it stop all events (inlcuding `ctrl+g`) on both sites?

Comment: @Halcyon I tried it and it prevented almost every keystroke **except** `Ctrl-G` ... I don't even. EDIT: a few others still worked, like `Ctrl-tab`, but `Ctrl-F` and `Ctrl-W` did not. I also tried `$(window)` in place of `$(document)`, same result

Comment: To be honest, I'm surprised the browser honors the `preventDefault()` (Chrome seems to). It seems that in the past ctrl+f could not be prevented. I don't know if browser vendors agree on behaviour.

Comment: Three things to try: 1) call e.stopPropagation() and e.stopImmediatePropagation(), 2) bind using addEventListener with true to cancel the event during the capture phase, and 3) bind and prevent the "keypress" event.

Comment: @Halcyon but it behaves differently between localhost and production.

Comment: This is clientside code that runs ***in*** the browser, changes in the server enviroment shouldn't have any effect on it, so something else must be going on